# Merging multiple dataframes and sort them out based on each df timestamp

Tags: mysql, r

Please excuse me if this might not sound very clear, but I will do my best with this challenging issue.
I have multiple dataframes.

Each data frame has hashed_user_id, server_timestap, and event.
An example of three data frames are as the following:

```
Data Frame 1

hashed_user_id  server_timestamp    event
user1          2017-04-27 15:25:12   AS
user2          2017-04-29 19:34:19   AS
user3          2017-05-01 21:28:17   AS
user4          2017-05-03 23:01:16   AS

Data Frame 2

hashed_user_id  server_timestamp    event
user1          2017-04-27 16:25:12   AV1
user2          2017-04-29 20:34:19   AV1
user5          2017-05-01 22:19:17   AV1
user6          2017-05-03 14:01:16   AV1

Data Frame 3

hashed_user_id  server_timestamp    event
user1          2017-04-27 17:25:12   AV2
user2          2017-04-29 15:34:19   AV2
user5          2017-05-01 21:28:17   AV2
user6          2017-05-03 23:01:16   AV2
```

The awaited table that I wish to have should merge all users in one table, and list all events sorted out by the server_timestamp. Therefore, the expected new dataframe will look like this :

```
Expected result:

hashed_user_id  sorted_event1   sorted_event2   sorted_event3
user1             AS                 AV1             AV2
user2             AV2                AS              AV1
user3             AS                 NA              NA
user4             AS                 NA              NA
user5             AV2                AV1
user6             AV1                AV2
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: check out `Reduce`, i.e. `Reduce(function(...)merge(..., by = 'hashed_user_id', all = TRUE), your_list))`

Comment: are these data.frames in a list ? (or are they named according to a consistent pattern)

Comment: each is a dataframe. Each event has been named based on some action.

Comment: Thank you @Sotos , the Reduce function seems to work somehow, but need to read about it more! thanks again :)

Comment: No problem. However, note that If you had provided a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), I would have also answered it.-- (For future reference)

Comment: @Sotos Will do next time. I appreciate your kindness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

# read your data 
dt1 <- tribble(
  ~hashed_user_id,~server_timestamp, ~event,
  "user1", "2017-04-27 15:25:12", "AS",
  "user2", "2017-04-29 19:34:19", "AS",
  "user3", "2017-05-01 21:28:17", "AS",
  "user4", "2017-05-03 23:01:16", "AS"
)

dt2 <- tribble(
  ~hashed_user_id,~server_timestamp, ~event,
  "user1", "2017-04-27 16:25:12", "AV1",
  "user2", "2017-04-29 20:34:19", "AV1",
  "user5", "2017-05-01 22:28:17", "AV1",
  "user6", "2017-05-03 14:01:16", "AV1"
)

dt3 <- tribble(
  ~hashed_user_id,~server_timestamp, ~event,
  "user1", "2017-04-27 17:25:12", "AV2",
  "user2", "2017-04-29 15:34:19", "AV2",
  "user5", "2017-05-01 21:28:17", "AV2",
  "user6", "2017-05-03 23:01:16", "AV2"
)

# solution
dt <- rbind(dt1, dt2, dt3) %>% 
  mutate(server_timestamp = as.POSIXct(server_timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>%
  group_by(hashed_user_id) %>%
  arrange(server_timestamp) %>%
  mutate(sorted_event_id = paste0("sorted_event", 1:n())) %>%
  select(-server_timestamp) %>%
  spread(sorted_event_id, event) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Amazing Amazing! Thank you very much! I was working on the reduce which gave some good results as well, but this one gives an exact solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution in the sense it doesn't give your expected output, but it's better to avoid having sorted data in different columns with `NAs` like this.

If you must still work in R with this later you'll have some dirty work to do again.

Consider having your sorted events in a vector, that you'll store in your `data.frame`/ `tibble`.

And start by putting these data.frames in a list! :)

```
res <- list(df1,df2,df3) %>%
  bind_rows %>%
  arrange(server_timestamp) %>%
  select(-server_timestamp) %>%
  nest(event,.key="sorted_events")
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#    hashed_user_id     sorted_events
# <chr>           <list>
#   1          user1 <tibble [3 x 1]>
#   2          user2 <tibble [3 x 1]>
#   3          user3 <tibble [1 x 1]>
#   4          user5 <tibble [2 x 1]>
#   5          user6 <tibble [2 x 1]>
#   6          user4 <tibble [1 x 1]>
res$sorted_events[[4]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 1
#    event
#    <chr>
#  1   AV2
#  2   AV1
```